# Calculate a Probability Of Computers Being Down

Tags: probability

Suppose that in a network of 3 computers, at a given time the event that the computer is down has unconditional probability $d_i$ for i = 1, 2, 3. Moreover, there is probability of power failure f, in which case all the computers are down, but given that there is no power failure the computers are up or down independently of each other. Calculate the probability that at this time there is at least one computer up.

My thoughts are:

P(all down) = P(all down, power failure) +  P(all down, no power failure) 
            = f + $d_1$$d_2$$d_3$(1 - f)

So, P(At least one up) = 1 - P(all down)

Can someone tell me if this is right?

Comment: Yes, seems to be right.